# understanding network tab on chrome console

Tags: ajax, console, xmlhttprequest

I'm in the process of writing an app that builds a table of Trello card data based on multiple API calls, and while the app works I'm finding the performance degrades considerably the longer it runs. The initial calls take a couple of seconds while later calls (after 100 runs or so) take upwards of a minute.

Looking at the XHR Network tab on my Chrome console, I can see the bulk of the call is taken by the 'Content Download' phase of the Ajax call. **I'm curious as to whether this means the issue is with my application or if the problem resides with the API I'm trying to call?** I'm a bit of a novice so my terminology is probably not appropriate here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Content Download time is the time during which your content is downloaded from the server.

Very long time can be due to slow connection client-side or server-side.

As you can see  TTFB (time to first byte) is about 200ms. So your server is starting sending data after 200ms. Your server process seems to be OK.

You can click on the Explanation link for further information.